# Flanking and swarms in 4e

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, monsters

Can swarms be flanked by two PCs? What if the swarm is occupying the same square as a PC?

Does a PC grant combat advantage to a swarm if a regular mob is adjacent in a flank? Does it matter if the swarm occupies the same square as the PC?

Does a PC grant combat advantage to a mob if a swarm is adjacent in a flank? ... in the same square?

Comment: Hey @Snowbody. Good first question. Welcome to the site!  Off the top of my head I don't think swarms have any special rules for flanking. I think you'd still need to be able to draw a line passing through opposite sides or corners of the target's space. But hopefully someone comes up with a more definite answer than that :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DDI Compendium states for the Swarm trait:

> The swarm can occupy the same space as
>   another creature, and an enemy can
>   enter its space, which is difficult
>   terrain. The swarm cannot be pulled,
>   pushed, or slid by melee or ranged
>   attacks. It can squeeze through any
>   opening that is large enough for at
>   least one of the creatures it
>   comprises.

And for flanking:

> Combat Advantage: You have combat
>   advantage against an enemy you flank.
>
> Opposite Sides: To flank an enemy, you
>   and an ally must be adjacent to the
>   enemy and on opposite sides or corners
>   of the enemy’s space. When in doubt
>   about whether two characters flank an
>   enemy, trace an imaginary line between
>   the centers of the characters’
>   squares. If the line passes through
>   opposite sides or corners of the
>   enemy’s space, the enemy is flanked.
>
> Must Be Able to Attack: You and your
>   ally must be able to attack the enemy,
>   whether you’re armed or unarmed. If
>   there’s no line of effect between your
>   enemy and either you or your ally, you
>   don’t flank. If you’re affected by an
>   effect that prevents you from taking
>   actions, you don’t flank.
>
> Large, Huge, and Gargantuan Creatures:
>   If a flanking creature’s space takes
>   up more than 1 square, the creature
>   gains combat advantage if any square
>   it occupies counts for flanking.

So I'd say there's no restriction for flanking swarms in the rules, though I can certainly see how it could be more difficult in "real life" than flanking a normal-sized creature.

Answer (score 11):

The key thing I'd focus on here is the rules for flanking.

> Trace an imaginary line between the centers of the characters’ squares. If the line passes through opposite sides or corners of the enemy’s space, the enemy is flanked.
>
> You and your ally must be able to attack the enemy, whether you’re armed or unarmed.

[image: Flanking Diagram]

**Q.** Can a swarm [red] be flanked by 2 PC's?
**A.** Yes [yellow line passes through opposite sides]. There are no special rules for flanking swarms to my knowledge.

**Q.** Can a swarm occupying the same square as a PC be flanked?
**A.** Yes [yellow line passes through opposite sides], but not by the occupied PC [green line does not pass through opposite sides].

**Q.** Does a PC grant combat advantage to a swarm if a regular mob is adjacent to it (and vice-versa)?
**A.** No [cyan line does not pass through opposite sides].

**Q.** Can a swarm flank a PC with another creature?
**A.** If the swarm can usually only attack creatures in its space (Reach 0), No [blue]. Some swarms have this property. Other swarms have a normal reach (Reach 1) and thus can flank as normal.

Comment: You also should remember that the enemy has to be able to attack you in order to be flanking, so a swarm that only has aura damage on the square it occupies will never be able to participate in a flank against you.

Comment: @Cthos true, but are there many swarms that only have aura damage? Browsing through a few of them in the compendium, they all have at least 1 standard attack action.

Comment: @dpatchery Lots of them do, but it doesn't actually have a range, so I assume that means they can only do damage within their aura.

Comment: This is interesting as I don't think you could flank swarms in D&D 3.5

Comment: @Cthos ahh that is right. While it can attack, it can't attack an adjacent enemy. Good point!

Comment: @mirv120 You can't in Pathfinder for sure, but I'm not sure about 3.5 (the d20srd.com doesn't say anything about it in Pathfinder), mostly to do with the "no discernible anatomy" thing. Though I am reasonably certain that 4e ditched that idea.

Comment: Remove the "in Pathfinder" from the parenthesis... I dunno how I managed that.

Comment: @Cthos I was probably channeling Pathfinder and assuming it was a holdover from 3.5

Comment: @cthos How do I determine if a swarm's standard attack has a range or not? I'm not seeing it. Forgive me if I just blew my perception roll, but where is it specifically listed in the monster entry?

Comment: @Snowbody It has an aura listing up at the top, usually "Aura 1", then under it's attacks section it will outline the attacks it has. If that attack doesn't have a range specified, it can only attack within its aura (which is the square it occupies), iirc.

Comment: @cthos - Aura 1 means just its own square? Aura 2 means its own square and the 8 around it? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Snowbody Yeah, I think you're correct. I'm trying to reconcile the differences between 3.5e and 4e in my brain. The last post of the thread (which I'm sure you're already aware of since you're involved in it. :) ) seems to imply you are correct http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?p=11214473. So mayhap swarms **can** flank. Weird.

Comment: @cthos ok, thanks, differences between editions can be confusing. My best one was "uh oh your character's at -12 he's dead" "No, not until he's at -32" "oh yeah, right negative bloodied value in 4e"

Comment: @cthos if you're not sure how a mechanic works, look it up and quote it. Aura 1 is each square surrounding the square the creature occupies. There is no range zero defined in the rules, however certain swarm creatures have attacks that only trigger if they are in the same square as another creature. By default though almost every creature in 4e has an MBA attack which would be melee which would be defaulted to attacking any square adjacent.